# strip all chars before first alpha char in string in PHP

Tags: php

I need to strip all the chars in a string before the first alpha char ie

```
"216 - Viera/Suntree N of Wickham/50" 
"384-Indialantic/Melbourne Beach"
```

need to return

```
"Viera/Suntree N of Wickham/50"
"Indialantic/Melbourne Beach"
```

here is my first try...which works but seems to me ugly as hell...

```
  $aListArea = str_split($row['listingArea']);
  $done=false;
  $stg=array();

  for ($i=0;$i<strlen($row['listingArea']);$i++) {
    if (!ctype_alpha($aListArea[$i]) && $done==false) {
      continue;
    }
    else {
      $stg[]=$aListArea[$i];
      $done=true;
    }
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to achieve this:

```
preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z]*/', '', $str);
```

**Explanation:**

- `/` - starting delimiter
- `^` - "start of string" anchor
- `[^A-Za-z]` - every character that isn't an alphabet (`^` negates the character class)
- `*` - repeat the previous quantity one or more times
- `/` -  ending delimiter

**Visualization:**

[image]

Effectively, it replaces everything between the beginning of the string and the first alphabet with nothing (`''`).

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/90553)

Comment: clean...i like it.  tyvm

Answer (score 0):

si la estructura es numero - texto

te propongo:

```
$cadena = explode ("-",$row['listingArea']);
$valor = ltrim ($cadena[1]);
```